# ImportError: cannot import name NumpyTest

Tags: python, numpy, wav, scipy, importerror

I am trying to read a *.wav file using scipy. I do it in the following way:

```
import scipy.io
x = scipy.io.wavfile.read('/usr/share/sounds/purple/receive.wav')
```

As a result I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy.io
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/scipy/io/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from numpy.testing import NumpyTest
ImportError: cannot import name NumpyTest
```

Does anybody know why scipy cannot import NumpyTest and how it can be fixed?

Comment: If I use "from scipy.io import wavfile" instead of "import scipy.io". I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have upgraded your numpy version but haven't installed a [corresponding scipy version](http://projects.scipy.org/scipy/ticket/916).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have numpy installed? The package is most likely called `numpy` or `python-numpy` if you are running Linux

If your OS package manager does not have numpy package, download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/)

Comment: I have numpy (version 1.4.0). For example "import numpy" causes no problems.